# Why does my python regex not work?

Tags: python, regex

I wanna replace all the chars which occur more than one time,I used Python's re.sub and my regex looks like this `data=re.sub('(.)\1+','##',data)`, But nothing happened...
Here is my Text:

> Text
>
> ※※※※※※※※※※※※※※※※※Chapter One※※※※※※※※※※※※※※※※※※
>
> This is the begining...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use raw string here, `1` is interpreted as octal and then its ASCII value present at its integer equivalent is used in the string.

```
>>> '\1'
'\x01'
>>> chr(01)
'\x01'
>>> '\101'
'A'
>>> chr(0101)
'A'
```

Use raw string to fix this:

```
>>> '(.)\1+'
'(.)\x01+'
>>> r'(.)\1+'  #Note the `r`
'(.)\\1+'
```

Comment: `\1` is interpreted as octal 1, which is then represented as `\x01` (hexadecimal). Try `\141` for size.

Answer (score 1):

Use a raw string, so the regex engine interprets backslashes instead of the Python parser. Just put an `r` in front of the string:

```
data=re.sub(r'(.)\1+', '##', data)
            ^ this r is the important bit
```

Otherwise, `\1` is interpreted as character value 1 instead of a backreference.